# How to use v-bind:height?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I dynamically set a height of an element?
I have a `v-carousel` but it takes way too much space on the screen.
So I need something like:

`v-bind:height="{ '300' : $vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown}"`

But it doesn't work.
I also though 'well maybe it's a string, so let's try a number'

`:height="{ 300 : $vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown }"`

And it didn't work either. tried also `300px` and `'300px'` and none of it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is to bind the height to a computed property like  :

```
  <v-carousel v-model="model" :height="customHeight">
```

and :

```
  computed:{
    customHeight(){
      return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown?300:500;
    }
  }
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/YzpBNeE)**

Comment: After a bit of experiments I ended up with vh.


`return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown? '30vh':
           this.$vuetify.breakpoint.md? '40vh':
           this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lg? '50vh':
           '60vh';`
 

Thank you, once again. I didn't even know I had to use computed property for that. Can you please refer to official docs where I can read more about it?